# OAuth2 Authentication in the IBM Social Business Toolkit

Tags: oauth-2.0, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I have a installation of IBM Connections 4.5 and the SBTPlayground on my Domino Server. Anyway I want to use it with the Playground on premise. But I can't find the right information for the custom environment. It wants OAuth2 - Consumer Key, OAuth2 - Consumer Secret and so on. So I have found many documentation about all. One of this with the WebSecurityStore but for this I need also actual URL's which I not found. 
My first step is to bring a OAuth2 configuration with Greenhouse Connections. 
The second step with Connections on premise.

So with this documentations are all not working, the URL's are not working. Or I can't register a app on Greenhouse, or any URL gives the keys back.

http: //heidloff.net/nh/home.nsf/article.xsp?id=12152011034545AMNHECAP.htm

http: //www.xpagescheatsheet.com/cheatsheet.nsf/135E58313968CEEB8825799100478A6F/$FILE/Ni9-CS-SocialTools-8.5x11%20PDF.pdf

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API+Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=Step_2_Obtain_authorization_code_sbt&content=apicontent

http://www.openntf.org/Projects/pmt.nsf/DA2F4D351A9F15B28625792D002D1F18/%24file/SocialEnabler111006.pdf

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

@Raphael use these URLS from the sbt.properties file

```
# Connections OAuth 2.0 Endpoint Parameters
connectionsOA2.url=https://qs.renovations.com:444
connectionsOA2.serviceName=SBTK
connectionsOA2.appId=SBTK
connectionsOA2.consumerKey=SBTK
connectionsOA2.consumerSecret=
connectionsOA2.authorizationURL=https://qs.renovations.com:444/oauth2/endpoint/connectionsProvider/authorize
connectionsOA2.accessTokenURL=https://qs.renovations.com:444/oauth2/endpoint/connectionsProvider/token
connectionsOA2.apiVersion=4.0
```

Register your oauth keys Using wsadmin.sh 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYGQH_4.5.0/admin/admin/r_admin_common_oauth_manage_list.html

Example is https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/blob/0f7237b6ff22fed631bde9e4e16ed9744506694c/samples/scripts/oauthQSI.py

```
import sys
execfile('oauthAdmin.py')
OAuthApplicationRegistrationService.addApplication(sys.argv[0],sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
clientSecret = OAuthApplicationRegistrationService.getApplicationById(sys.argv[0]).get('client_secret')
print clientSecret
```

you can invoke it using a script 
#

```
Parameters
USER=$1
PASSWORD=$2
CLIENTID=$3
APPID=$4
URL=$5
#Starts WSAdmin
cd /local/con/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/bin/
/local/con/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/bin/wsadmin.sh -user $USER -password $PASSWORD -lang jython -port 8883 -f /local/qsi/bin/con/oauthQSI.py $CLIENTID $APPID $URL
```